# what is the best way to make my folders invisible / restricted in twistd?

Tags: python, twisted

a fews days ago, i tried to learn the python twisted..
and this is how i make my webserver :

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.web import static, server, script
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
import os

class NotFound(Resource):
    isLeaf=True
    def render(self, request):
        return "Sorry... the page you're requesting is not found / forbidden"

class myStaticFile(static.File):
    def directoryListing(self):
        return self.childNotFound

#root=static.file(os.getcwd()+"/www")
root=myStaticFile(os.getcwd()+"/www")
root.indexNames=['index.py']
root.ignoreExt(".py")
root.processors = {'.py': script.ResourceScript}
root.childNotFound=NotFound()
application = service.Application('web')
sc = service.IServiceCollection(application) 
i = internet.TCPServer(8080, server.Site(root))#@UndefinedVariable
i.setServiceParent(sc)
```

in my code, i make an instance class for twisted.web.static.File and `override` the `directoryListing`.
so when user try to access my resource folder (`http://localhost:8080/resource/` or `http://localhost:8080/resource/css`), it will return a notFound page.
but he can still open/read the `http://localhost:8080/resource/css/style.css`.
it works...

what i want to know is.. is this the correct way to do that???
is there another 'perfect' way ?
i was looking for a config that disable directoryListing like `root.dirListing=False`. but no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a reasonable way to do it.  You can also use `twisted.web.resource.NoResource` or `twisted.web.resource.Forbidden` instead of defining your own `NotFound`.